# What are "low tier" and "high tier" spells?

Tags: defend-the-rook

I've seen upgrades for the sorceress mentioning "low tier" and "hier tier" spells, the latter of which apparently have charges. **What are these?**

When I attack with her, I don't have an option to change the tier, or use charges, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. They are the spells the *player* casts

[image]

I was confused because I thought the sorceress was casting spells, but the upgrades only give her buffs in response to the player's spells.